# Trouble inserting blank characters in an inoremap <expr> statement

Tags: vim

I'm trying to make a <Space> keymap that inserts padding around the cursor when it is inside empty brackets. Essentially, I desire [.] -> [ . ], where the period is the cursor position. Everything in the following code is working as expected for me, but I run into trouble at the 3rd exec statement in the for loop:

```
let bracket_pairs = {'{':'}', '(':')', '[':']'}
  
def InEmptyBrackets(left_brack: string, right_brack: string): bool
   return functions#CharAt(-1) == left_brack && functions#CharAt(0) == right_brack
enddef
  
  
for [key, value] in items(bracket_pairs)

   " auto insert closing bracket
   exec "inoremap " . key . " " . key . value . "<Esc>i"

   " auto format indentation when inside empty brackets on 'Enter' keypress
   exec "inoremap <expr> <CR> InEmptyBrackets('" . key . "','" . value . "') ? \"\<CR>\<Esc>O\" : \"\<CR>\""

   " pad cursor on both sides when inside empty brackets on 'Space' keypress
   exec "inoremap <expr> <Space> InEmptyBrackets('" . key . "','" . value . "') ? \"\<Space>\<Space>\<Esc>i\" : \"\<Space>\""   
                                                         
   " skip closing bracket if already present when typed
   exec "inoremap <expr> " . value . " functions#CharAt(0) == '" . value . "' ? \"\<Esc>la\" : \"" . value . "\""

endfor
```

I've tried many variations on the `\"\<Space>\"` term including `\" \"`, `' '`, etc. with no luck. Any old crusty Vim veterans out there know a solution?

Here is the CharAt() function if necessary.

```
def functions#CharAt(distance_from_cursor: number): string
   return getline('.')[col('.') + distance_from_cursor - 1]
enddef
```

Comment: It's usually `"\<Space>"`.

Comment: Also, you might want to check your syntax: mixing legacy vimscript and vim9script might not be a good idea, especially in a snippet that others may execute in their own environment.

Comment: Correct, but the whole remap is in an `exec " ... "` statement, so the nested double quotes in `"\<Space>"` must be escaped like `\"\<Space>\"`